# Prediction of random sum of binomial variables

Tags: mathematical-statistics, prediction-interval

Let us consider $\xi\sim\sum\limits_{i=1}^v\text{Bin}(1,p):=\sum\limits_v\eta$.

Where $v$ is random variable with unknown distribution. Let $\mathbb{E}v^m<\infty \quad\forall m$.

We know, that 
$$\mathbb{E}\xi= \mathbb{E}\sum\limits_v\eta  = \mathbb{E}v \cdot \mathbb{E}\eta $$
$$\text{Var}\xi= \text{Var}\sum\limits_v\eta = \mathbb{E}v \cdot\text{Var}\eta + \text{Var} v \cdot (\mathbb{E}\eta)^2 $$

Let us concider sample $(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n)$.

For given $\gamma$ and $k$ I need to obtain  $a$ and $b$ such that  $$\Pr(a\lt\sum\limits_{j=1}^k\xi_j \lt b)=\gamma.$$

Comment: do you really want confidence interval on the sum of $\xi$ or $p$? Use the fact that the sum of binomials is another binomial.

Comment: Yes, for the sum. 
It will be again random sum of binomials, that's the point.

Comment: Do you know the distribution of $v$?

Comment: @jbowman, no, that's the point too :D

Comment: "Confidence interval," as usually defined, makes no sense here, because its target is a *parameter* of the model, not a random variable.  Could you clarify what you're asking for?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I'm wrong about the terminology.
For some $\gamma$ and k I need to obtain such $a$ and $b$ that $ \text{P}(a<\sum\limits_{i=1}^k\xi<b)=\gamma $

Comment: @whuber It's like an insurance model. When we have statistics about previous claims and want to predict the next one.

Comment: That's not what a confidence interval does: you're not asking an intelligible question.  But if you would edit it to describe what you actually do need, it ought to be interesting and answerable.

Comment: Thank you for the edit.  However, your question has little to do with its set-up, It is wholly independent of $v$, because you have stipulated its value $k.$   You're merely asking how to compute Binomial probabilities.

Comment: Sorry,maybe I didn't write it very clearly. But $\sum\limits_1^k\xi$ is equvalent to  $\sum\limits_1^k\sum\limits_{j=1}^{v_i} \text{Bin}(1,p)$ and is distributed almost as $\text{Bin}(\sum\limits_{i=1}^k v_i ,p)$. So, $k$ is not value of $v$

Comment: Ah, I see: the notation is missing a subscript.  Let's correct that and reopen your post.  But just to be clear: may we presume (a) $a$ and $b$ are to be estimated from the sample and (b) the "$\xi_j$" referenced in the sum are *random variables* that are *independent of the sample?*

Comment: @whuber Thanks! Both answers are "yes"